# Cakephp 3 Sorting of another model is not working

Tags: sorting, cakephp-3.0, paginator

I have two models **Provides** & E**x**penses
Problem: I have list of users with column `Expenses.type_of_document`, `Expenses.change_to,Expenses.date`, `Provider.rut`, `Provider.nickname`. Each & Every column has sorting but on `Provider.rut` and `Provider.nickname` sorting is not working.

**ExpensesTable.php:**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->table('expenses');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsToMany('Events', [
        'foreignKey' => 'expense_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'event_id',
        'joinTable' => 'events_expenses'
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Providers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'expense_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'provider_id',
        'joinTable' => 'expenses_providers'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('ExpensesProviders', [
        'foreignKey' => 'expense_id'
    ]);
}
```

**ProviderTable.php**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('providers');
    $this->displayField('name');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('Products', [
        'foreignKey' => 'provider_id'
    ]);
}
```

**ExpensesProvidersTable.php**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('expenses_providers');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Providers', [
        'foreignKey' => 'provider_id'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Expenses', [
        'foreignKey' => 'expense_id'
    ]);
}
```

**ExpensesController.php**

```
public function index(){
    $this->paginate=[‘contain’ => [‘Providers’],‘sortWhitelist’ => [‘Expenses.type_of_document’,‘Expenses.charge_to’,‘Expenses.date_of_issue’,‘Providers.rut’,‘Providers.nickname’,]];$expenses = $this->paginate($this->Expenses->find()->contain([‘Events’, ‘Providers’]));$this->set(compact(‘expenses’, ‘opt’));$this->set(’_serialize’, [‘expenses’]);}
```

**index.ctp**

```
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.type_of_document', 'Tipo') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.charge_to', 'Cargo') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.date_of_issue', 'Fecha') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Providers.rut', 'Rut') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Providers.nickname', 'Proveedor') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.document_number', 'N° Dcto.') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.details', 'Detalle') ?></th>
            <th class="right"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.amount_total', 'Total') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.payment_status', 'Estado') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.way_to_pay', 'Forma') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.created', 'Ingreso') ?></th>
            <th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.paid_by', 'Pagado por') ?></th>
            <!--<th class="left"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('AccountingMonths.date', 'Mes') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('payment_date', 'Fecha de pago') ?></th>
            <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('accounting_statement', 'Estado de cuenta') ?></th>-->
            <th class="actions center"><?= __('Acciones') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($expenses as $expense): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="left"><?= $expense->type_of_document ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= (strcmp($expense->charge_to, 'evento') == 0 and !empty($expense->events))? $expense->events[0]->code : $expense->charge_to ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= $this->Utils->chileanTimeZone($expense->date_of_issue, 'DDMMYYYY', 'UTC') ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= h(!empty($expense->providers)? $expense->providers[0]->rut : '') ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= h(!empty($expense->providers)? $expense->providers[0]->nickname : '') ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= h($expense->document_number) ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= h($expense->detail) ?></td>
            <td class="right"><?= "$ ".$this->Number->format($expense->amount_total, ['locale' => 'es_CL']) ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= h($expense->payment_status) ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= h($expense->way_to_pay) ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= $this->Utils->chileanTimeZone($expense->created, 'DDMMYYYY', 'UTC') ?></td>
            <td class="left"><?= h($expense->paid_by) ?></td>
            <td class="actions center">
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $expense->id]) ?>
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $expense->id]) ?>
                <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $expense->id], ['confirm' => __('Estás segur@ de eliminar # {0}?', $expense->document_number)]) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?= $this->element('pagination') ?>
```

It does not work to order

```
<?= $this->Paginator->sort('Providers.rut', 'Rut') ?> <?= $this->Paginator->sort('Providers.nickname', 'Proveedor') ?>
```

Let me know any solution you have.

ERROR SQL

```
SELECT Expenses.id AS `Expenses__id`, Expenses.document_number AS `Expenses__document_number`, Expenses.charge_to AS `Expenses__charge_to`, Expenses.type_of_document AS `Expenses__type_of_document`, Expenses.date_of_issue AS `Expenses__date_of_issue`, Expenses.accounting_month_date AS `Expenses__accounting_month_date`, Expenses.detail AS `Expenses__detail`, Expenses.amount_total AS `Expenses__amount_total`, Expenses.payment_status AS `Expenses__payment_status`, Expenses.way_to_pay AS `Expenses__way_to_pay`, Expenses.payment_date AS `Expenses__payment_date`, Expenses.accounting_statement AS `Expenses__accounting_statement`, Expenses.paid_by AS `Expenses__paid_by`, Expenses.created AS `Expenses__created`, Expenses.modified AS `Expenses__modified`, Expenses.rut AS `Expenses__rut`, Expenses.provider_name AS `Expenses__provider_name` FROM expenses Expenses ORDER BY Providers.nickname asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

URL: http://localhost/pweventos/expenses?url=expenses&sort=Providers.nickname&direction=asc

Comment: You have a one-to-many relationship in your models, so sorting like this won't work: the associated records are loaded in a second query, not with a join. You're only referencing the first such record in the index page. If that's because there's only ever one, then I'd suggest that you adjust your database structure to the more appropriate one-to-one relation, and then the sorting should just fix itself. If you really do need one-to-many, then I think you'll need to do something in your index function to force a join, presumably with a where clause to limit it to a single provider per expense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExpensesController.php

```
    function index(){
    $this->paginate = [
                'contain' => ['Providers'],
                'sortWhitelist' => [
                    'Expenses.type_of_document',
                    'Expenses.charge_to',
                    'Expenses.date_of_issue',
                    'Providers.rut',
                    'Providers.nickname',
    ]
    ];
    }
```

**index.ctp**

```
 <thead>
            <tr>
 <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.type_of_document', 'Tipo') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.charge_to', 'Cargo') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Expenses.date_of_issue', 'Fecha') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Providers.rut', 'Rut') ?></th>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Providers.nickname', 'Proveedor') ?></th>
<th scope="actions center"><?= __('Acciones') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```